# Ошибка Instantiate

Tags: c#, unity3d

хочу сделать так чтобы создавалось 10 кубов но вылазит ошибка код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class createground : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject groundpart;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        int quantity = 10;

        for (int i = 0;i < quantity;i ++)
        {
            for (float offset = 0f; offset < 5f; offset++)
            {
                Instantiate(groundpart, groundpart.transform.position.x += offset, Quaternion.identity);
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: просто вылазит и всё? такая страшна и такая "буууууу!" или там что-то написано в ней всё же содержательное, что поможет понять проблему?

Answer (score 0):

```
groundpart.transform.position.x += offset
```

Как вы думаете, что делает эта конструкция? В пределах метода `Instantiate`.
Почему думаете, что она валидна?